# The python system (using wxpython) suddenly exit with exit code -1073741819

Tags: python, wxpython

I am writing a Login page using MU with wxPython. (I am very new to Python)

The following is what I want to do:

1. Have a Login frame which allows user to enter username and password, after that the user click the login button
2. The Login frame will then be destroyed so that the main body of the program can get the Username and Password from the Login frame
3. The main program will pass the Username and Password to a function to check whether the Username and Password are valid or not.
4. After checking, the program will start a Loading frame to simulate a checking process (which is fake), this frame will be destroy after 0.5 second.
5. After the Loading frame destroyed, if the Username or Password is wrong, then the Login frame will be established again to ask the user to enter the information again, and then repeat the above step until the Username and Password are valid.

The below link is the video showing the right process of what I am talking about:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12ZMkbZ6phcurO22Qk3RVYkGyYcidpKE2/view?usp=sharing

However, a problem suddenly appeared, by chance, the system will suddenly exit with exit code -1073741819, when this happened, the situation is like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12_8nwG31kpGsWGndeqFYl5aJ2zHXwQje/view?usp=sharing

And when this happened, it didn't leave any Traceback for me to debug, all it left is just like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1olyRki1UeiCw0GpBLdrP7FhXXXoE0Xub/view?usp=sharing

Moreover, as I mentioned, this situation happens by chance, I can't even repeat this error intentionally.

The below is the code I established the Login frame, I tried to simplify it for everyone to read easily:

```
Login_status = False
while Login_status == False:

    Login_page_app = []
    Login_page_app = wx.App()
    Login_page = Login()
    Login_page_app.MainLoop()

    Login_Username = Login_page.getUsername()
    Login_Password = Login_page.getPassword()

    Login_status = Check_login_status(Login_Username, Login_Password)
```

After countless time of tracking (using the debug mode in Mu), I discovered that when the system exited suddenly, the program ended here:

```
    Login_page_app.MainLoop()
```

I found that, when the program came to this, it will refer to the code in core.py:

```
    def MainLoop(self):
        """
        Execute the main GUI event loop
        """
        rv = wx.PyApp.MainLoop(self)
        self.RestoreStdio()
        return rv
```

Then it will stop at:

```
        rv = wx.PyApp.MainLoop(self)
```

After that, the system will exit suddenly with exit code -1073741819.

With my little knowledge of programing, I don't know what to do next... so can anyone help me please!

(If the above information is not enough to provide a full picture of the problem, please let me know, I will try my best to give more details)

Answer (score 0):

After trying, I discovered that, because I use wx.Timer to destroy the Loading frame after 0.5 second, but after the Loading frame has been destroyed, I haven't stop the wx.Timer, so the Timer keep running and destroy the Loading frame for every 0.5 second. Therefore, when the Timer destroyed the Loading frame second time, there is no Loading frame there and causing the system crash.
Now, I solved the problem when I stop the Timer after destroying the loading frame.

Orginal code:

```
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.onClose, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(5000)

    def onClose(self, event):
        self.Destroy()
```

New code:

```
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.onClose, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(5000)

    def onClose(self, event):
        self.Destroy()
        self.timer.Stop()
```